# CSV Parse + Upload Django ( Error: can't concat bytes to InMemoryUploadedFile)

Tags: python, django, csv

I parse a CSV and when I try to save it, I get the error 'TypeError: can't concat bytes to InMemoryUploadedFile'.

```
    upload_obj = UploadField(csv=True)
    csv_upload = request.FILES.get('uploads', None)

    csv_parsed = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(csv_upload, 'utf-8'), delimiter=',')

   [parse loop then...]


   try:
        upload_obj.save(request=request, content_list=csv_upload)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error:', e)
```

I get the error when attempting to save.

Comment: What your definition of `UploadField`?

Comment: Edit: added upload field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform a `InMemoryUploadedFile` into a `NamedTemporaryFile`, so then you can treat it as a normal file:

```
file_temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
file_temp.write(csv_upload.read())
print(file_temp.name) # This is the path.
```

When you finish just do `file_temp.close()` to delete it.